# What is $\omega_\omega$?

Tags: set-theory

We all know $\omega_0$ the first countably infinite ordinal. And of course $\omega_1$, the first uncountably infinite one. But what is $\omega_\omega$?

This seems like a beast. Is its existence provable? What is this ordinal like?

Comment: The definition for $\omega_\omega$ is $$\bigcup\{\omega_\xi :\xi<\omega\}.$$ You can see [limit ordinal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal), specially the examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "provable"? Provable from what? About it being a beast, it may very well be smaller than the cardinality of the continuum. Whether or not this counts as a beast is a matter of taste.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton About the size, for me $\varepsilon_0$ is terribly big, and it is much smaller than $\omega_1$. So... I think it depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of $\omega_\omega$ - and in general of $\omega_\alpha$ for **any** ordinal $\alpha$ - is indeed provable in ZFC. The key axiom (scheme) is **replacement** (in particular, choice plays no role). The proof roughly goes like this:

- Suppose otherwise, and let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that "$\omega_\alpha$ doesn't exist" (phrased appropriately).
- By Replacement, the class of ordinals in bijection with $X$ forms a set, for any set $X$ *(this is a multi-step argument)*; so we can look at the set $S$ of ordinals in bijection with $\omega_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$ (EDIT: and the finite ordinals).
- Now $S$ is an ordinal (any downwards-closed set of ordinals is an ordinal), and it's not hard to show that $S$ doesn't inject into any $\omega_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ but every proper initial segment of it does inject into some $\omega_\beta$ with $\beta<\alpha$.
- So $S=\omega_\alpha$. Oops.

It turns out that replacement is necessary: e.g. $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of ZC (= ZFC without replacement), but $V_{\omega+\omega}$ doesn't even think $\omega_1$ exists!

---

As to how large $\omega_\omega$ is, that's a bit hard to answer. One key fact is that it is (as tomasz comments) consistent with ZFC that $\vert\mathbb{R}\vert>\omega_\omega$. Indeed, it turns out that pretty much the only thing one can prove about the continuum in ZFC is that [it is uncountable and has uncountable cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)). So, e.g., it could be $\aleph_1$ (this is the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis)) but it can't be $\aleph_0$, and it can't be $\aleph_\omega$ (= $\omega_\omega$) since that has countable cofinality *(and indeed one of the most important facts about $\omega_\omega$ is that it is the least infinite [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal) cardinal)*, but it could be e.g. $$\aleph_{\omega^{\omega^\omega}+\omega^2\cdot 37+12}.$$

One of the major themes of modern set theory is that the ZFC axioms - even plus large cardinals! - are absolutely terrible about proving things about cardinal exponentiation. On the other hand, [one of Shelah's fundamental contributions to set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCF_theory) is that ZFC *can* prove some surprising things about cardinal exponentiation: for example, that $$\mbox{If $2^{\aleph_n}<\aleph_\omega$ for all $n\in\omega$, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$.}$$ (The hypothesis there can be abbreviated as "$\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal.") No, we don't know if "$4$" is optimal, there.

Comment: The fact $\omega_\omega$ is the least infinite singular cardinal is really neat. I didn't realize it first, thanks!

Comment: One should be a bit more careful about $V_{\omega+\omega}$ thinking that $\omega_1$ doesn't exist. The von Neumann ordinal, yes. An uncountable well-ordered sets do exists in $V_{\omega+\omega}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed, I meant exactly what I wrote and no more.

Comment: Would you please help with my confusion. You have $S$ in bijection with some $\omega_{\beta}$ yet later $S$ doesn't inject into any $\omega_{\beta}$. Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew $S$ is not in bijection with some $\omega_\beta$, the *elements of $S$* are each individually in bijection with some $\omega_\beta$ (or, as per my edit, are finite). Just like $\omega_1$ isn't in bijection with $\omega_0$ but each element of $\omega_1$ is in bijection with $\omega_0$ (or is finite).

Comment: Pertinent to your third remark: is it possible that there exists a set of ordinals which is not downward closed? Since $S$, as a subset of **ON**, each element is transitive and wellordered by $\in$? Or maybe the way to show it is $\bigcup S$ is an ordinal? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew Sure, $\{17\}$ isn't downwards closed. That said, you're right that for *any* set $S$ of ordinals its union $\bigcup S$ is an ordinal again.

Comment: Thanks. I guess $\{17\}$ is an example of what I just now came across: **WF** excludes sets that are built up from themselves.